# Onsen ui navigation with parameters

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using onsen ui with typescript and angularJS with an ons-sliding-menu:

```
  <ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.html" main-page="link/to/some/page.html" side="left"
                     var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
   </ons-sliding-menu>

   <ons-template id="menu.html">
      <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
         <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>
         <ons-list class="menu-list">
            <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('link/to/some/page.html', {closeMenu: true})">
               Home
            </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('link/to/some/other/page.html', {closeMenu: true})">
               Home
            </ons-list-item>
 </ons-list>
      </ons-page>
   </ons-template>
```

This gives me my menu, an it is fine.... When I navigated to *link/to/some/page.html*, I need to push some parameters to *link/to/some/other/page.html* using that code:

```
 $scope.myNavigator.pushPage("link/to/some/other/page.html", {param1: "bla", param2: "blabla"});
```

I read the parameters using this code:

```
var page = $scope.myNavigator.getCurrentPage();
console.log(page.options.param1); // Should return "bla"
```

This gives me an error, because *param1* is not defined. I am not sure why this happens, because it is the code from the onsenUI-page.
I think this is because I already defined the page *link/to/some/other/page.html* in my *ons-sliding-menu* ....

Every page looks like this:

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
   <div ng-controller="ControllerOfPage">
      <ons-page>
         <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="left">
               <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
                  <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
               </ons-toolbar-button>
            </div>
            <div class="center">{{title}}</div>
         </ons-toolbar>
PAGE CONTENT
      </ons-page>
   </div>
</ons-navigator>
```

Any suggestions? Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say every page looks like the one you pasted. Do you have several `<ons-navigator>` tags? You should really only need one.

If you do

```
$scope.navigator.pushPage('somepage.html', {param1: 'bla'});
```

You should be able to do

```
console.log($scope.navigator.getCurrentPage().options.param1);
```

See pen:

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/OPJRPe

Do you have the navigator attached to some scope that is parent of the scope of the controller for the page you push?

In your parent controller you could do:

```
ons.ready(function() {
  $scope.navigator = $window.myNavigator
});
```

And then use that object in the child controllers.

Comment: Hi, thank You for the reply. In my scenario: Where do I have to place the ons-navigator element. I just put the start tag behind the <body> of the HTML-Page, then the ons-sliding-menu with the complete menue and I close the ons-navigator before </body>. This seems to be wrong

Comment: It seems that you push a page which has a navigator in it, and it has the same name so you'll overwrite the global navigator variable.

Could you please show the code where $scope.myNavigator is set? You should be able to send parameters with `pushPage()` so I'm thinking it's maybe not the same navigator when you try to retrieve the parameters.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the "ons.ready(function().." stuff. I am using typescript and I haven't found any typescript definitions for onsen ui - so    
ons.ready(function() {$scope.navigator = $window.myNavigator}); says me "Couldn't find symbole ons"

Comment: Ah ok - the navigator is loaded correctly, but now I get an "Fail to fire "pageinit" event. Attach "ons-page" element to the document after initialization." exception. This is still because of the ons.reads(...) stuff

Comment: Ahh the problem was: I used "link/to/some/page.html" as a parameter for "main-page" in ons-sliding-menu and I also used it as a target for ng-click="menu.setMainPage(...) - if I removed the link from "main-page" everything is fine... I don't understand this, but it works with this modification....

Comment: may i know what about the param is a variable. for example var param = 'bla' and then {param1: param} it doesn't work. do u guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I facing same problem, my solution for this is basicaly combine both in something like this

```
<ons-sliding-menu
        menu-page="menu.html"
        side="left"
        max-slide-distance="250px" 
        var="menu">
        <div class="main">
            <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="home.html"></ons-navigator>
        </div>          
    </ons-sliding-menu>
```

In this way you can use both SlideMenu and Navigator pattern