# Fail to fetch PageView from ons-page element in onsen ui

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

i am newbie to angularjs and onsen ui,I am making a demo using onsen ui for passing values to another page,I succedd in that,but for that i removed all "ons-navigator" tag from html pages and put it in only "index.html" page as per suggested in [ons-navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905869/onsen-ui-navigation-with-parameters)

**Fail to fetch PageView from ons-page element**
so can anybuddy pls suggest me how to resolve this.

my code is as below:
**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">    
  <ons-navigator animation="slide" var="gallery">  
.
.
.
</ons-navigator>
</body>
```

**firstpage.html**

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar modifier="opacity">
    <div class="left">
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon-round" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Category-list</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <!-- <div class="app-page" id="app-id" ng-controller="menuController" ng-bind-html-unsafe="category">-->

  <div class="app-page" id="app-id" ng-controller="menuController">
    <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
  </div>
</ons-page>
```

**secondpage.html**

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar modifier="opacity">
    <div class="left">
      <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon-round" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Category-list</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <!-- <div class="app-page" id="app-id" ng-controller="menuController" ng-bind-html-unsafe="category">-->

  <div class="app-page" id="app-id" ng-controller="listingController">
    <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
  </div>
</ons-page>
```