# Onsen UI pass variables to another page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

According to [Onsen ui navigation with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905869/onsen-ui-navigation-with-parameters), I have tried and it works.

However, the params there are static. I would like to pass a variable which is based on some requests.

For example,

```
var param1 = 'bla';
$scope.navigator.pushPage('somepage.html', {param1: param1});
```

Is there any way to do it? Thank you experts here!

Comment: If `param1` is defined on the scope, you can definitely pass it to `somepage.html`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> var param1 = 'bla';
>
> $scope.navigator.pushPage('somepage.html',
> {param1: param1});

**It depends on what version of Onsen-UI you are using**

If Onsen **v2** - [documentions](https://onsen.io/v2/docs/angular1/navigation.html)

myNavigator.topPage.data

If Onsen **v1** - [documentions](https://onsen.io/v1/guide.html#PageNavigation)

myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.data